# Difference between not dict and not dict=={}

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Came in today and debugged to find that there was a deviation in the behaviour I predicted as a result of `not aDict` being treated differently to `not aDict=={}`.  Could someone in the know highlight the differences between these two forms please.

Deviation was caused on the following line of code

```
if not aDictA and not aDictB:
```

Both were equal to {} and yet the if condition didn't return true.

line of code changed to

```
if not aDictA=={} and not aDictB=={}:
```

and code worked as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right in thinking that empty dictionaries are `False` in a boolean context. Therefore, `not {}` and `empty_dict == {}` are equivalent, however...

In the first one, you are checking if they are `False`.

```
>>> not {}
True
```

But in the second one, you are actually checking if they are empty (therefore `False`) and then reversing it with the `not`.

```
>>> not not {}  # This is basically what you are doing.
False
```

You get different results because you are not actually testing the same condition.